# Fluent Nhibernate Automapping. An association refers to an unmapped base class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following situation:

**AssemblyX** with db entities refers external **assemblyY** and use its classes *as base classes.* **AssemblyX** adds some navigation properties if necessary.

*Of course I can copy all this entites and use automapper to solve my problem, but I have a reason to inherit existent entities.*

So, I have `Foo {}` class in **assemblyY** and create `Bar: Foo {}` in **assemblyX**. Configure fluent automapping to ignore `Foo (.IgnoreBase<Foo>())`. Everything works good. But **assemblyY** has another entity `Rab` (that is covered by fluent automapping) that has a navigation property that refers to `Foo`. That cause an exception: "An association from the table Rab refers to an unmapped class: Foo".

```
public class Foo // .IgnoreBase<Foo>() - I require only derived Bar in DB
{
    public virtual Guid Id {get; set;}        
}

public class Bar: Foo
{
    public virtual Guid Id {get; set;}
    // Some new properties
}

public class Rab
{
    public virtual Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo // reference to unmapped class, I could not change type to Bar (external assembly)
}
```

How can I solve it. I tried to inherit the Rab and create `new Foo` property with Bar type, but unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom IAutomappingConfiguration to determine which type or member should be mapped :

```
class MyConfig : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
        {
            public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
            {
                return  !(typeof(Foo)).IsAssignableFrom(type);
            }

            public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
            {
                return  !(typeof(Foo)).IsAssignableFrom(member.PropertyType);                }
        }
```

Then you can use your config like this :

```
AutoPersistenceModel model = new AutoPersistenceModel(new MyConfig());
```

And Finally :

```
Fluently.Configure()

                    .Mappings(m => m.UsePersistenceModel(model))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
```